# What's the maximal number of q-arrays of $A_7(7,d)?$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, cryptography, coding-theory

$ A_q(n, d) $ is the maximum number of a $q$-arrays of length n and minimum distance at least d.

What's the best known exact values of $ A_7(7,d)$ for $d=1$ to $7$?

Comment: What have you tried/investigated already? Apart from that, I think you want a best lower bound (a minimum number of code words you could send)

Comment: @Pieter21 No, There are upper bounds like [Singleton bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound). But i want to find eact value of maximum possible number of codewords.

Comment: http://codetables.de/

Answer (score 0):

All code words of length 6 + parity value (sum) would create a code with distance 2. Singleton bound shows it can't be better than that.

So $A_7(7,2) = 7^6$

Comment: Can you extend your solution for $d>2$ distances?